# cakePHP won't route to default layout and gives [MissingActionException] error

Tags: cakephp, layout, controller

I have a very strange thing happening with just one controller action. It's a view action that works and routes as expected for other similar controllers, but won't route for one specific controller action. What's happening is this:

I've got a 'galleries' controller and when I choose a gallery to view from the index action, it will take me to the 'view' action but won't display in the default layout. The index action will correctly route to and use the default layout but the view action won't.

I also have a posts controller that's setup identically and has no problems, so I'm confident it's not a problem with how the model/controller for the galleries controller is setup. And since the default layout is working for all other controllers I don't know why it wouldn't work for just this one?

In trying to solve this I found that if I changed it to route to the 'admin' layout there was no problem.

In the error logs, here are the messages I'm getting. What's hard to understand is why the default layout works for all other controllers, but doesn't work for this one galleries view method:

> 2013-11-27 15:06:21 Error: [MissingActionException] Action GalleriesController::js() could not be found.
>
> #0 C:\wamp\www\DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
>   #1 C:\wamp\www\DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(GalleriesController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
>
> 2013-11-27 15:06:21 Error: [MissingActionException] Action GalleriesController::css() could not be found.
>
> #0 C:\wamp\www\DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
>   #1 C:\wamp\www\DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(GalleriesController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
>
> 2013-11-27 15:06:21 Error: [MissingActionException] Action GalleriesController::img() could not be found.
>
> #0 C:\wamp\www\DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
>   #1 C:\wamp\www\DOMAIN-NAME-HERE\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(GalleriesController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))

I've never seen this type of error message before, and since I don't get it when any other controller action is called it's quite a mystery.

This is what's in the view method:

```
    public function show($slug=null) {
    $this->layout='default';            
    if (!$slug) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid gallery', true));
      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('gallery', $this->Gallery->findBySlug($slug));
}
```

Here is what's in the default.ctp layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
 <title>WEBSITE TITLE</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->

<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/bootstrap.less" media="all" />

<script src="js/less-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <?php echo $this->element('headerMain'); ?>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">

      <?php echo $this->element('leftNavBar'); ?>
      </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
            <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>

  </div><!-- row -->


  </div>

</div>

  <?php echo $this->element('footerMain'); ?>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The code for the view template is:

```
<div class="col-md-8">

  <h2>Gallery photos</h2>
  <br />


      <ul>

    <?php foreach ($gallery ['Photo'] as $photo): ?>

       <li>  

        <?php
            echo $this->Html->image(
                $photo['imgPath'], 
                array('title' => $photo['alt_tag']), 
                array('escape' => false)
                );
        ?>

       </li>

      <?php endforeach; ?>                  
      </ul>
```

thanks, Paul

Comment: Please paste the content of this view

Comment: Guillemo I've added the layout content above. thanks

Comment: Paul, I meant the View of the action you are calling

Comment: Guillemo, I've added the contents of the view file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, comment all elements and see if it works, the only clue that I have is that something is calling  GalleriesController::js() which apparently is not a function in your controller.

My first guess is that in one of those elements you are doing a requestAction to the aforementioned action. How am I sure? easy, just add a dummy function in galleries controller with this body

```
public function js() {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guillemo. Sadly that didn't work at all. I worked on this quite a bit and decided to upgrade to the most current version of cake and use Mark Story's asset compress plugin to deal with my less files. both those actions resolved the issue. Since I just couldn't find a patter to explain this, since other controllers didn't have this problem I had to find something that would resolve this and allow me to move on. Thanks a lot for your help.